# Floating point numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science

In a certain computer represents numbers in base2, if the distance between 7 and the next largest floating-point number is $2^{-12}$. What is the distance between 70 and the next largest floating number on that computer?

Comment: Here’s a hint: $7_{\rm{ten}}=111.000\dots_{\rm{two}}$. The next largest representable number is given as $111.000000000001_{\rm{two}}$, so this tells you how many base-two digits are kept track of. Now write $70_{\rm{ten}}$ in binary, increment the last of the kept-track-of digits (the same number of digits as for $7$), then convert back to base ten.

Answer (score 3):

Written in base 2, the smallest floating-point number larger than 7 is $7+2^{-12} = 111.000000000001$ (with 11 zeros). From this, you can conclude the mantissa has 15 bits, and so when we increment 70 by the smallest amount possible, we get $1000110.00000001$; this distance is $2^{-8}$.